# How to concatenate two arrays in NodeJS / ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

What is the most expedient means of merging two identical JSON arrays on in a NodeJS / Express app?  I have three web services... two data api services and one "wrapper" service.  Both data services have identical objects and schemas (pulling from Mongo via Mongoose).  I would like the "wrapper" service to make calls to BOTH data services and send back the results as one combined response.

The objects are both identical:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "14e016a2-9eb8-4f83-b597-bda8ad747adb",
            "name": "Item A 01",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "4040c450-4624-4341-9a80-211814d630ab",
            "name": "Item A 02 - Renamed",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "4fc4e0f7-36bc-4a87-a280-97e4f84a4a43",
            "name": "Item A 04 - Renamed",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to combine both result sets:

```
    request('http://localhost:8080/itemsa', function(err, response, body){
        if (err || response.statusCode != 200){ res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failure service 01' }); return; }

        var objA = JSON.parse(body);

        request('http://localhost:8081/itemsb', function(err, response, body) {
            if (err || response.statusCode != 200) {
                res.status(500).send({message: 'Failure service 02'});
                return;
            }

            var objB = JSON.parse(body);

            var objC = {
                items: []
            };

            objC.items.concat(objA.items);
            objC.items.concat(objB.items);

            res.send(objC);
        });
    });
```

However, I cannot find a concat or merge operation that works:

```
{
    "items" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: You're working on some kind of old CRT terminal that doesn't let you cut and paste?

Comment: In the future, please put the actual code in the question. SO does syntax highlighting automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Aaah, was using the `concat` function incorrectly...

```
    request('http://localhost:8080/itemsa', function(err, response, body){
        if (err || response.statusCode != 200){ res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failure service 01' }); return; }

        var objA = JSON.parse(body);

        request('http://localhost:8081/itemsb', function(err, response, body) {
            if (err || response.statusCode != 200) {
                res.status(500).send({message: 'Failure service 02'});
                return;
            }

            var objB = JSON.parse(body);

            var objC = {
                items: []
            };

            //objC.items.concat(objA.items);
            //objC.items.concat(objB.items);

            objC.items = objA.items.concat(objB.items);

            res.send(objC);
        });
    });
```

The `concat` method produces an output object...

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "14e016a2-9eb8-4f83-b597-bda8ad747adb",
            "name": "Item A 01",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "4040c450-4624-4341-9a80-211814d630ab",
            "name": "Item A 02 - Renamed",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "4fc4e0f7-36bc-4a87-a280-97e4f84a4a43",
            "name": "Item A 04 - Renamed",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "1997b22b-541c-4338-950f-a97566f0cfc6",
            "name": "Item B 01",
            "__v": 0
        },
            {
            "_id": "ef2eb8e8-6eaf-426b-a69a-0dd04c0b473f",
            "name": "Item B 02",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```